# Soundcloud client authentication window has a syntax error causing window.opener to be null

Tags: soundcloud

Soundcloud client authentication window has a syntax error causing window.opener to be null.

This syntax error is causing my main tab (window) to now be disconnected from this window.

on the callback I am using window.opener to manage the refreshing of my main application.

Will Soundcloud fix their syntax error? can anyone else confirm they have this issue too?

[image]

Comment: this seems to now be working and it also seems the syntax error was not the issue